# Proof of Plancherel Formula for Trig. Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Problem**: Show $||f||_2^2 = \sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(n)|^2$

I do not know how this holds in general, but this identity was proposed in a section of my book called "Trigonometric Polynomials" so I assume $f$ is a trig. polynomial.

**Proof**:
\begin{align*}
||f||_2^2 &= \int_{[0,1]} f(x)\bar{f(x)} dx\\
&= \int_{[0,1]} (\sum\limits_{n = -N}^N c_ne_n)(\sum\limits_{n = -N}^N \bar{c_ne_n}) dx \\
&= \int_{[0,1]} \sum\limits_{n = -N}^N |c_n|^2 dx\\
&= \sum\limits_{n = -N}^N |c_n|^2 dx \\
&= \sum\limits_{n = -N}^N |\hat{f}(n)|^2 dx \\
&= \sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(n)|^2 dx
\end{align*}

I skipped a couple of steps here for brevity, but how does this look?

Comment: The point is that it true for $L^2$ functions, not just for trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. However, with some clarification, the question posed does actually insist that I assume $f$ is a trig. polynomial -- this is supposed to be like a stepping stone toward the more rigorous result I think. That being the case, does my work look ok?